# PHP loop from SQL table with results looped into a string and it not saving why?

Tags: php, sql, loops

I am trying to save 'newentryname' as the field name in my code - but I'm always getting an error, when I examine the sql table it saves the first time after refreshing the table, but then after it doesn't save

I am pulling the fields from another table and looping them into the input fields, and I am then trying to get the fieldnames into a loop to put into a string to save in the SQL, to be used elsewhere.

Section 1: This is connects to the separate table inside the same wordpress SQL table - the $wpdb variable is contains the sql connection information

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    // Add table name as variable to include prefix  
    $rowname = $wpdb->prefix . 'rowname';
    $results =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $rowname ");
    // $selected = $item['name'];
```

Section 2: This section of the code echo's out the input fields as checkboxes in a loop

```
/** Loop through the $results and add each as a checkbox options */

    $checked = ' ';

foreach($results as $result) :

    $resultid = $result->ID;
    $resultrowname = $result->name;
    $options.= sprintf("\t".'<input 

        type="checkbox" ' . '%1$s' . 'value="%3$s" name="newentryname[]" >%3$s'."\n", $checked, $resultid, $resultrowname); 

endforeach;
```

Note: above I'm not sure if the newentryname[] is what is causing the error - I can't tell what information this is is sending to the database ideally I only want it to store the data to be used in Section 3 below:

Section 3:  This should be combining the data input from the above table, and adding it to a string, so it can be saved in a single field - but I'm not sure if the code is getting that far.

```
$fieldname=$item['fieldname'];

     // You have to loop through the array of checked box values ...
     $newentryname="";
     foreach($fieldname as $entry):
     $newentryname .= $entry.", ";

endforeach;

echo $options;
?>
```

EDIT: The above is inside a function
    functionname($item)
and the code to insert it into the database is: 
    $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
I am wondering if it's the fieldname 'newentryname' also being submitted to the database, and how would I get around this problem, and how would I submit the data from section three into the database instead

Comment: "but I'm always getting an error".  Care to share what that error is?

Comment: Should `$fieldname=$item['fieldname'];` be `$fieldname=$item['newentryname'];` instead? Is this a direct copy/paste of your code, or did you re-type it here maybe? Also could you break up the code blocks above into each stage for clarity of how it flows.

Comment: The error is just a generic error message that doesn't pin down what the error is other than it's not saved in the sql table:

Comment: $result = $wpdb->insert($table_suli, $item);

                $item['id'] = $wpdb->insert_id;

                if ($result) {

                    $message = __('Item was successfully saved', 'custom_table_suppli');

                } else {

                    $notice = __('There was an error while saving item', 'custom_table_suppli');

                }

Comment: the above is the code that generates the error - which is: There was an error while saving item

Comment: I did change the code so the field names were different in my question (I did this just for security reasons)

Comment: There are 3 sections to my code:

Comment: section 1:

 global $wpdb;
        // Add table name as variable to include prefix  
        $rowname = $wpdb->prefix . 'rowname';
        $results =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $rowname ");
        // $selected = $item['name'];

This accesses the sql database of the other table  - the wpdb contains the sql link in wordpress

Comment: Please put your code directly in the question, not in comments.  Code is virtually unreadable in comments.

Comment: Section 2: This echo's out the fields:

        $checked = ' ';

    foreach($results as $result) :

        $resultid = $result->ID;
        $resultrowname = $result->name;
        $options.= sprintf("\t".'<input 
           
            type="checkbox" ' . '%1$s' . 'value="%3$s" name="newentryname[]" >%3$s'."\n", $checked, $resultid, $resultrowname); 
            
    endforeach;

This seems to echo out the fields but I'm not sure if the newentryname[] is getting submitted and causing the error

Comment: I've now edited the question to break down the code

Comment: Does it produce any output html code?  If so, please add it.  I am suspicious of newentryname[] as a name for input.   Since you do a foreach, you will have multiple inputs with name="newentryname[]", which is not good.  Each input should have a unique name.

Comment: I'm not getting any html output in my code sorry
I think you are in the right area with the name="newentryname[]", but you should be able to have multiple checkboxes with the same field name or at least certainly without an sql database - perhaps there needs to be a work around when working with sql ???

Comment: No I mean in your form, each input has to have a unique name.  When you submit your form, each input will be stored in $_POST[].  If you have 2 with the same name, there is no way to differentiate in your $_POST array to extract the values.  I would get a counter going in the while and put a name value with that counter (ex newentryname$counter).  And do not use [] inside a name value, how will you address it in $_POST?  [] is already used for array manipulation.  Might be theoretically correct (I am no sure), but it will be confusing!  Oh and you do echo $options; so something is sent out ;-)

Comment: @Nic `newentryname[]` is how you would send an _array_ of input values. It is perfectly valid and would be accessed by doing `$_POST['newentryname'][$i]` (where `$i` is the numeric index of the specific element in the array you want to access)

Comment: Well I'll be d...!  Ok thanks, learn something every day!  I will definitely use that!  Thanks!

Comment: Cheers Nic
echo options echo's out the input fields correctly

Comment: Patrick has just put something far more well put than I would have Nic

Comment: You guys are all awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add $n = 0 and n++ in the foreach loop

```
$checked = ' ';
$n = 0;
foreach($results as $result) :

$resultid = $result->ID;
$resultrowname = $result->name;
$n++;
$options.= sprintf("\t".'<input 

    type="checkbox" ' . '%1$s' . 'value="%3$s" name="newentryname[]" >%3$s'."\n", $checked, $resultid, $resultrowname); 

endforeach;
```

and then I replaced this section of the code below:

```
$fieldname=$item['fieldname'];

 // You have to loop through the array of checked box values ...
 $newentryname="";
 foreach($fieldname as $entry):
 $newentryname .= $entry.", ";

endforeach;

echo $options;
```

With this code, to handle the output and echo out the output so it can be used to be sent elsewhere

```
   $fieldname = $_POST['fieldname'];

     foreach($fieldname as $entry):
     $output .= $entry.", ";

endforeach;

echo $output;
```

I still get the error which is because of the way my array structure works, it still doesn't like the array within an array, but to correct the above code the above is what needs to be done.